# Есть ли возможность открыть определенное модальное окно по ссылке

Tags: php, jquery

Добрый день,
Сайт php+jquery+mysql
На страницу выводятся блоки с иконками.
При нажатии на блок открывается модальное окно, через ajax запрашиваются данные для этого блока по id. Данные приходят и мы с помощью jquery расставляем данные в нужные места модального окна. Все красиво.
Но возникла задача отправить ссылку на конкретный блок по почте.
Что бы человек получив ссылку кликнул на ссылку и у него открылся сайт с уже открытым модальным окном в которое подгружена инфа конкретного блока.

Что-то я даже не могу начать представлять куда капать и как это можно реализовать.
Буду признателен за любую подсказку в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: Модальных окошек в браузере больше не существует:(

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо!!!
Ткнули носом.
Сделал так:

```
var parm = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?')).split(/[&?]{1}[\w\d]+=/);
    console.log(parm[1]);
    if (parm[1] != '' && $.isNumeric(parm[1])) {
        open_post(parm[1]);
    }
```

Comment: window.location.hash будет короче и надежнее (что если parm[1] на деле будет в parm[2]?). Он возвращает fragment после #.

Answer (score 0):

Без кода и понимания, как это реализовано у вас, сложно дать конкретный ответ. Вот как это делается для модальных окон Bootstrap:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if(window.location.href.indexOf('#myModal') != -1) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

});
```

Теперь при переходе по ссылке вида http://www.example.com/page.php#myModal будет открываться соответствующее модальное окно.

Еще несколько вариантов тут - https://gist.github.com/MrDys/3512455

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае нужно писать обработчик на самой странице, где должно быть модальное окно.

Передать запрос на инициализацию модального окна можно по урлу, через get параметры (?modal=ВАШ_ID_ОКНА) или hash (#modal=ВАШ_ID_ОКНА).

На самой же странице обрабатывать эти параметры и инициализировать окно (через новую функцию или просто имитацию клика).

Так же вы можете обработать get параметры сервером (hash обработать возможно только js) и открыть страницу уже с окном, без инициализации js.
Но как подсказывает опыт - писать это будете дольше, хоть и работать будет быстрее, т.к. это все происходить будет до события load.